# implode a subsection of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have a post array and I want to implode only a subsection of it. For instance, I have:

```
'value1' => 'a'
'value2' => 'b'
'value3' => 'c'
'name1' => 'Fred'
'name2' => 'Mary'
'name3' => 'James'
'value4' => 'd'
```

I will get an arbitrary number of names amongst the rest of the variables. From those, I want a concatenated list of those names, interpolated with commas. So for the above array, the output should be:

```
Fred,Mary,James
```

But for any given post, there could be any number (well, not *any*) of names, all in the form *name#*, where *#* is a sequential number.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Are the names always associated with keys with the pattern `'name#'` where `#` is a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop could do the trick:

```
$names = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos(strtolower($k), 'name') === 0) {
        $names[] = $v;
    }
}
echo implode(",", $names);
```

[**Try it here.**](http://www.ideone.com/6Oe5O)

Comment: Nice but I would replace `print_r()` with... oh, you know.

Comment: That's just about right, but the last line should be something like `implode($names,',');`

Comment: @BoltClock, @user151841 - Happy now :p

Comment: Actually, it also looks like the `$arr` in `foreach` should be $_POST ( and we should be doing validation :), and `$e` should be `$v`?

Comment: @Karim Isn't `print_r(implode( ... ))` a bit redundant? ;)

Comment: @user151841 - fixed, a demo is forthcoming.

Comment: @karim79 very peachy. Why `trim($k)`?

Comment: @user151841 - I don't know actually, good point. `strtolower` is probably more appropriate, or even `stripos` for that matter.

Comment: @karim79 why not nothing? If it's not 'namex', it's improperly formatted.

Comment: @user151841 - This is also true, but what if some douchebag page designer changes the case of one of the 'namex's? I don't know. Maybe I'm overthinking this :)

Answer (score 0):

If names means strings more than 1 character long, here's what you can do:

```
foreach($array as $val)
    if(strlen($val) > 1)
         $result[] = $val;

echo implode(',', $result);
```

---

If names means values where keys start with name, here's what you can do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
    if(substr($key,0,4) == 'name')
         $result[] = $val;

echo implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put names into a post array.. php handles this very well....

```
<input type="text" name="names[1]" value="" />
```

then you can access this by

```
$_POST['names'][1]
```

And continuing...

```
foreach($_POST['names'] as $name => $value)
{
    echo $value . ", "; 
}
```